# Unit testing @Asynchronous method in a spy in java 7

Tags: java, junit, mockito, future

I am trying to test some awful legacy code (Java 7)
I need to spy on a stateless service, but call an asynchronous method

I get the error

> **Object does not represent an actual Future**

How should I try and test this?

```
@InjectMocks
private OrderDataImport spyImporter;

/* has spyImporter as a dependency */
@InjectMocks
private ImportService sut; /* system under test */

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // create spy
    spyImporter = Mockito.spy(new OrderDataImport());
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public Test() {
   sut.import();
}
```

Import Code

```
class ImportService {
   @EJB
   private OrderDataImport dependency;


   public boolean import() {
       List<Future<Result>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

       int THREAD_COUNT = 3;
       while (THREAD_COUNT-- > 0)
           resultList.add(dependency.create(...));

       for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
           /* Object does not represent an actual Future */
           Result result = resultList.get(i).get(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
       }           
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need mockito's static method when() , just try it

`doReturn({Future subclass instance}).when({reference spyImporter}).get(anyInt(),xx)`

Answer (score 0):

You should not spy on anything else in your test than the SUT itself.

`OrderDataImport` is a dependency that you should aim to mock, not spy.

You also should use the `@InjectMocks` on the SUT only:

```
@Mock
private OrderDataImport importerStub;

@InjectMocks
private ImportService sut; 

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public Test() {
   // Arrange
   when(importerStub.create(..)).thenReturn(/* Future instance */);

   // Act
   sut.import();
}
```

In the end, I see that you don't really need any spying here.

Comment: I need to spy on it, as it's part of the legacy code that needs to execute.

Comment: So the ImportService is not the SUT actually here?

Comment: yes it is, but I am also testing the create method, I can't stub it out, that's why it's a spy and not a mock.

Comment: Then i would say you should test that inside a test class where OrderDataImport  is the SUT